# Java heap space error when saving changes

Tags: javascript, eclipse, heap-memory, sapui5

I'm developing a project in SAPUI5 using Eclipse Juno SR2.

Everything was working fine until yesterday I started to get an error message every time I save something (I believe this only happens in this specific project): An internal error occurred during: "Updating JavaScript Index".

I've tried to search about this, some of the posts I've found talk about Maven preference, but I can't find it in my Ecplise.

Here's what I have in the log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-07-16 14:26:56.393
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating JavaScript Index".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 4 4 2014-07-16 14:23:44.603
!MESSAGE Background Indexer Crash Recovery
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? It's disabling any thing on development, but it's rather annoying.

Thank you.

Eva

Comment: Open the Error Log view and tell us the exact details of the error that you find there.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the log. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the amount of heap space allocated to Eclipse. You can do this via the [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file. The params that control heap space are `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.

Pay careful attention to the format of `eclipse.ini` as it is quite picky.

Comment: I changed the parameter on the .ini file -Xmx512m to -Xmx2048m. Still get the error.

Comment: Might be an obvious thing, but you did re-start Eclipse after adjusting the `ini` file, right?

Comment: Several times, even restarted the computer :)

Comment: Somehow it stopped showing the error message. Thanks anyway!